# "OpenDNS" bypasses VPN and alternate DNS servers

Tags: networking, vpn, dns

Sometimes I use an internet connection monitored by a service known as OpenDNS. This service blocks some websites that I like to use. To circumvent this I

- Use Google Public DNS servers
- Use a VPN

However, I have noticed that some websites are still blocked, however not in the way that you would think. When trying to access vpnbook.com, I was greeted by the "this is categorized as a proxy/anonymizer" page. However, putting in the IP for this website directly landed me on the site.

At this point, I was very confused, so I

- Double checked my DNS settings
- Made sure my VPN was working
- Did a DNS flush

All to no avail. Why is this happening? It makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: It's possible that your internet connection is also filtered by a simple HTTP firewall (looking at packets and blocking specific hostnames).

Comment: @GiantTree Wouldn't this be encrypted because of my VPN? If not, is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Your DNS requests are seemingly going outside your VPN. Google for "vpn dns leak" there is a plenty of possibilities for misconfiguration.